# shouldAutorotate Not called - [Not using storyboard]

Tags: ios, objective-c

My UIViewController not called the method shouldAutorotate.
 tried several ways for forcefully show the VC in portrait mode.

Sample code is below :

**AppDelegate.m**

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[VCLogin alloc] init]];
[self.window setRootViewController:self.navController];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

**VCLogin.m**

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [self.navigationController.visibleViewController shouldAutorotate];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

And enabled Device Orientation as 'Portrait',  'Landscape Left' and 'Landscape Right'

Any idea will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to protect a particular vc to be in portrait mode ?

Comment: Yes. I'm using iOS 10 sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

Added a custom UINavigationController class.

**navigationControllerViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface navigationControllerViewController : UINavigationController

@end
```

and override the following methods

**navigationControllerViewController.m**

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return [self.visibleViewController shouldAutorotate];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask )supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return [self.visibleViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return [self.visibleViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}
```

then assigned this custom navigation controller inside 
AppDelegate.m file

```
// Replace
self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[VCMasterView alloc] init]];

// With
self.navController = [[navigationControllerViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[VCMasterView alloc] init]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following code :

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
//or return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait , etc as your requirement
}
```

Comment: actually I'm looking for to maintain only one vc in portrait mode in the entire application.

Comment: make that viewcontroller in storyboard with sizeclass : compact width and regular height

Comment: Unfortunately my project not under in storyboard . It's keeps xib files only.

Comment: then use autolayout and sizeclasses in that xib and use compact width and regular height for it